# An integral similar to integrating the Beta function

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function

Peace be upon you,

I have the following definite integral for the mathematical expectation of some distribution
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1 z^2\int_{\max(z-1,-1)}^{\min(0,z)} (z-y)^a(-y)^b \ ,dy \,dz
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
a,b\in(-1,0)
\end{align*}
I have the [following result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+int+z%5E2+%28z-y%29%5Ea+%28-y%29%5Eb+dy+dz) for the answer of the related definite integral.
Though, it is very long, but I could take its advantage if Hypergeometric function was defined in either of Octave, Scilab or Apache Common Math (java library); because I need to use it in my program in Java and these are java connection bridges to open-source math world.

However, I think that it is not necessary for me to exhaust my self by such formula when my integral is a specifically special case of the indefinite one. I suppose that it can be written in terms of a simpler well-known function (something similar to incomplete Beta function).

Here I see that it has some problems to become a function of incomplete Beta function
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-1}^0 z^2\int_{-1}^z (z-y)^a(-y)^b\,dy\,dz &&+\int_0^1 z^2\int_{z-1}^0 (z-y)^a(-y)^b \, dy \, dz\\
&\int_{-1}^0 z^2\int_{-z}^1 (z+y)^a y^b \, dy \, dz &&+\int_0^1 z^2\int_0^{1-z} (z+y)^a y^b \, dy \, dz \\
&\int_{-1}^0 z^2 \int_0^{1+z} y^a (-z+y)^b \, dy \, dz &&+\int_0^1 z^2\int_0^{1-z} (z+y)^a y^b \, dy \, dz \\
&\int_{-1}^0 (-1)^{b}z^{2+a+b} \int_0^{1+z} (\frac{y}{z})^a (1-\frac{y}{z})^b \, dy \, dz&&+\int_0^1 (-1)^b z^{2+a+b}\int_0^{1-z} (\frac{-y}{z})^b (1-\frac{-y}{z})^a \, dy \, dz\\
\end{align*}
As you can see the internal terms are similar but different (regarding $dy$) from incomplete Beta function:
\begin{align*}
B\left(x; a,b \right)= \int_0^x t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt
\end{align*}
However, I do not persist that it becomes in terms of the incomplete Beta function. I only want to analytically solve this to become in terms of a well-known function and run it on Octave or Scilab or Apache common math. Any idea?

Comment: Other open source mathematics packages have built-in capabilities for numerical computations with hypergeometric functions. Sage, maxima, and pari, for example.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment; at least I know that there exists a way.however, don't you think that my computations (or some similar one) can result in a simpler answer?

Comment: Are you completely sure octave(matlab for free) doesn't have an inbuilt functionality? I did a quick search on octave string hy (hygecdf/pdf) and bam there is the hyper geometric function and cdf/pdf so with regards to the hyper geometric is slightly off..

Comment: cdf of the Hypergeometric function is a special case of the generalized Hypergeometric function [ ${_3F_2(1,k+1-K,k+1-n;k+2,N+k+2-K-n;1)}$ ]; but as you see in the Wolfram page I need  some functions like $_2F_1(-a,b+1;b+2;\frac{y}{z})$.